# How does one resize a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

So I have a dropdown menu like this:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
    <option value="">Caption</option>
    <option value="someoption">SomeOption</option>
</select>
```

Neither adding `width="20"` nor `style="width: 20px"` sets the width as I want to. I observed, that in the browser, actually different code is shown; the `select` is transformed into a `div`, so it seems like that transformation doesn't inherit the changed width.

How would one go about setting a different width for such a menu?

Comment: surely there is some js that is doing the trick... why don't you add some css rules for the generated div?

Comment: @DanieleFois Because that would be a blueprint for all dropdown menus not just for a single one

Comment: then post more code...

Comment: What more code could I give you? This literally is the example code from the documentation

Comment: you can post the output for example...

Comment: Or tell us what plugins you are using, that may help.

Comment: No plugins. Also, changing the output div doesn't do anything as well. But I'll post the output. Give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, proposed by Indrek Siitan from the [Gitter Chat](https://gitter.im/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI):

Have a div around it with a specific width and then append the `fluid` class to the dropdown. Namely:

```
<div style="width: 20px">
    <select class="ui fluid search dropdown">
        <option value="">Caption</option>
        <option value="someoption">SomeOption</option>
    </select>
<div>
```

Comment: Without the `fluid` class, the dropdown itself wouldn't get resized and applying a width to the generated `div` directly did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<div>` that's added has a class or id, use CSS to target it.

```
<style>
#id{
  /*styles*/
 }
.class{
  /*styles*/
}
.parentClass>div{
  /*styles*/
}
#selectWrapper>div{
  /*styles*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: Right. Could've come up with that myself :)

Comment: Although, that would change all dropdown menus, but I only want to change singular ones

Comment: I edited it, so if you add a class or id to the parent element, it will target all inner divs

Comment: Ok, so put it inside a `span`?

Comment: Um, thats what id's are for.... Just give it a unique id and style that.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it does not work, because applying a width to the generated `div` directly just didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the select with an identifier and targeting the `select` from there.

```css
.wrapper select {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>


<div class='wrapper'>
  <select class="ui search dropdown">
      <option value="">Caption</option>
      <option value="someoption">SomeOption</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is about a Semantic UI dropdown, not a standard one and this answer has the same problem as the 2 before it

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<select id="drpdwn" class="ui search dropdown"> <option value="">Caption</option> <option value="someoption">SomeOption</option> </select>

#drpdwn{ width: 20px;}
```

id has higher priority than class. This one works